# Mysql Inner Join a table with matching key column but null

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I am trying to join 4 tables.

`registration_mt`, `admission_mt`, `student_mt`, and `schoolyear_student_lt`

Currently `registration_mt`, `admission_mt` and `student_mt` tables have **1 record** each.
There are no problems inner-joining all three of them **except** for `schoolyear_student_lt` which has no records yet.

I want to be able to get the columns of `schoolyear_student_lt` and join it with the result set of the 3 other tables even when the matching key `student_id` **HAS** OR **HAS-NO** records

I want to add `schoolyear_id`, `student_id`, `gradelevel_id`, `section_id`, `passed`from **schoolyear_student_lt** to the result set I get from my join query `where isActive = 0`;

`CREATE` table statements

```
CREATE TABLE `registration_mt` (
  `registration_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`registration_id`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `admission_mt` (
  `admission_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `registration_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isComplete` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `completion_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`admission_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `registration_id_UNIQUE` (`registration_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_admission_mtTABLE_registration_idCOL` FOREIGN KEY (`registration_id`) REFERENCES `registration_mt` (`registration_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ;

CREATE TABLE `schoolyear_student_lt` (
  `schoolyear_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gradelevel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `section_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `passed` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_schoolyear_idCOL_student_idCOL` (`schoolyear_id`,`student_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `student_mt` (
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `registration_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `entry_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `isGraduated` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `date_graduated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `isActive` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `registration_id_UNIQUE` (`registration_id`),
  KEY `fk_student_mtTABLE_registration_idCOL_idx` (`registration_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_student_mtTABLE_registration_idCOL` FOREIGN KEY (`registration_id`) REFERENCES `registration_mt` (`registration_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

My `INNER-JOIN` statement

```
SELECT 

a.admission_id, 
a.isComplete, 
a.completion_date,
s.student_id,
s.entry_date,
s.isGraduated, 
s.date_graduated, 
s.isActive

FROM admission_mt a 
INNER JOIN registration_mt r ON a.registration_id = r.registration_id
INNER JOIN student_mt s ON s.registration_id = a.registration_id
-- INNER JOIN schoolyear_student_lt sslt ON s.student_id = sslt.student_id
-- LEFT JOIN schoolyear_student_lt sslt ON s.student_id = sslt.student_id 


 WHERE 

 s.isActive = 0 ;
```

`INSERT` statements to **registration_mt**, **admission_mt**, and **student_mt** tables

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO registration_mt(student_type) VALUES('New'); -- insert to registration_mt

INSERT INTO admission_mt(registration_id)
VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID()); --insert to admissiont_mt

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE admission_mt 
SET isComplete = 1 
WHERE registration_id = 1;

INSERT INTO student_mt(registration_id)
VALUES(1); --insert to student_mt

COMMIT;
```

I commented out the `-- INNER JOIN schoolyear_student_lt sslt ON s.student_id = sslt.student_id` because I get no results when I include it in my select query since there are no records yet in **schoolyear_student_lt** table.

This is the current resultset I get. There are no columns from **schoolyear_student_lt** table which I wish to add even when `NULL` and even when `NOT NULL` on `schoolyear_student_lt.student_id`

`LEFT-JOIN` doesn't display the columns from **schoolyear_student_lt** when `NULL`

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What about a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: If you want to join a table and include records that don't have a matching row in `schoolyear_student_lt`, then that is an `outer join` by definition. So use the correct join-type.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, I tried it but didn't work. I get the same result set as shown on screenshot.

Comment: @piet.t I tried LEFT JOIN / LEFT OUTER JOIN but get the same result similar to what's on screenshot.

Comment: please show the exact statement you tried when using `left join` - including the select-list and what is or is not commented.

Comment: @piet.t Thanks. It's now working. My bad for not including the columns when I first tried. It's all good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

The idea of an left outer join is that it takes the rows of left relation and fills the fields of the right relation with `NULL` if there is no join 
partner.

There is also a right outer join...

Comment: Thanks for the reference link.